# how can I remember my variable out if

Tags: javascript, html

How can I remember my variable `tempValue` outside `if` to give it as a parameter to other function? Because however it returns zero...

```js
function rememberFirstOperand()
{   
  var rep1 = /[/|*|+|-]/;
  var rep2 = /[0-9](?=[*|/|+|-])/;
  var tempValue=0;
  if (rep1.test(calculator.answer.value))
  {   
    tempValue=calculator.answer.value;
    calculator.answer.value='';
  }
  return tempValue;
}
```

Comment: If it is returning 0 then your if condition is evaluating as false, are you sure your regular expressions are matching something in `calculator.answer.value`

Comment: Are you sure it is going into the if?

Comment: It's should be right now. Can you create a snippet or bin with this problem?